# How to access my server files on Google Cloud when no instance appears?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So, I picked up an old project to maintain and don't have much context for it. But I need to access the machine to remove some files there that r causing errors on npm install. But, when I did enter the Google Cloud Painel, the server is running on the website but had no instance running. I don't know much about Google Cloud, so how its possible that the instance is not appearing to me? Even tho I know that exists and appears some information, but I wasn't able to find a way to access it, someone can help me? If it's too hard to explain here, we can find a way to talk.
[You can see that has "Create Instance" on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZYax.png)

Comment: Your first item to figure out is which Google Cloud service is your application running on. Compute Engine is just one of many services. There is Firestore, App Engine, Cloud Run, Kubernetes, etc. I recommend first creating an inventory of everything (services, storage, etc) in the project before touching anything. Then make sure you have backups and that you know how to restore from backups.

Comment: Hmm I see, gonna take a look further to find out which is. Thanks for the tip man :D